# Should I use just one word or both?

Tags: word-usage

Which sentence shows certainty and is more direct?

**A**

> He will **either** choose project 1 **or** project 2.

**B**

> He will *probably* **either** choose project 1 **or** 2.

or this other version of the 2nd example.

> He will *probably* choose **either** project 1 **or** 2.

I think the first example shows more certainty and is more direct since it doesn't have probably which indicates assumption, but either also shows assumption. Do we even need to add **probably** here? Do tenses have anything to do with the sentence?

Comment: Is it *guaranteed* he will choose one of the two options? If so, "probably" is not needed. If there is a chance he will choose both, or neither, then you would need it.

Comment: "He will choose either Project 1 or Project 2" is a better version of (A). The option is between the two projects, not between choosing and doing something else.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Can someone add an overall answer so I can give them credit?